# If a European bank keeps debiting illegal account management charges, is there a way to block debits or even enforce a SEPA direct debit charge back?

Tags: european-union, breach-of-contract, banking, fees, accounting

If the European bank at which you have an account keeps debiting illegal account management charges from said account (e.g. an arbitrary 300% of the amount contractually agreed) and doesn't react to complaints, is there technically any way to block further debits and maybe even enforce a SEPA direct debit charge back (as guaranteed by EU regulation for 8 weeks from the booking date)? Are debits conducted *by your own bank* the same legally as any other direct debit by 3rd parties?

Or to dumb down the question: Who would be the "bigger fish" with regard to EU banks that private customers can get involved in their own interest? Are there some financial regulators/enforcers/institutions/agencies in EU law that keep banks in check when they misbehave?

Clarifications as per request:

1. It is not my own bank, but I know of a relevant case.
2. It is in the same country as mine.
3. The bank is acting for itself, no third party involved.
4. To my knowledge, no SEPA mandate was issued to the bank explicitly, but this question cannot be answered by the enquirer as the answer to this question is what his question is about.

Comment: This sounds very much as if you need a *lawyer*, not general information from a web forum. To improve the answers here, clarify if it **is** your bank or a different one, if it is in the same country as yours, if the bank is acting for itself or for some third party claiming to have a SEPA mandate, and if you have ever given a SEPA mandate for direct charges to that bank or to that third party.

Comment: @PMF, when I read "generalized" questions like that, I always fear that the quest for universality has caused the omission of key information. Q: "Can they do that?" A: "Usually not, but there may be special circumstances."

Comment: @o.m. Probably yes. This question lacks many important details, but I don't like casting close votes on new user's contributions when there's a chance the question can be improved.

Comment: @o.m. The question has been updated as per your request.

Comment: @PMF No, this question does not lack many important details. I have added information as requested, however, only point 3 actually adds related information. Point 2 would only be of relevance if you have an answer in mind that depends on the national law of a specific country and if the answer to the question depends on nationality. Point 1 has absolutely no bearing for the question (off-topic/meta). Point 4 is partially what the question is about.

Comment: I presume that one very straightforward way to block further debits would be to close the account...?

Comment: @NateEldredge Not an option for the moment, there is too much linked to this account. Migrating it would be a huge hussle for multiple parties. Not looking for a brute-force solution, therefore, but something more handy/sharp-edged that puts the bank in her place. For instance, if debits by the bank follow the same legal framework as any other SEPA direct debit mandate, who has **authority over the bank** that could enforce charge backs in the name of customers?

Comment: Or to put it differently: Who would be the "bigger fish" with regard to the bank that one could get involved? Are there some financial regulators/enforcers/institutions/agencies in EU law that keep banks in check when they misbehave (and which can be approached by private customers)?

Comment: Yes, there are regulators, no we won’t be able to tell you which one to turn to without knowing what country this is happening in.

Comment: From your comments to my answer, the question comes down to "a bank is applying management charges in accordance with the wrong table of prices (we believe). What can we do to make them apply the right table of prices?" The customer could show them the original paperwork, indicating the agreed account type, and ask on what basis that was changed.

Comment: Cross-posted to Money.SE: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/151624/22489

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it is not a SEPA *transfer* at all, it is a dispute about charges. There are two possible scenarios:

- The bank and the customer disagree about what management charges are due, and the bank applies *their interpretation of the contract* anyway.
- The bank and the customer agree that lower management charges are due, but because of some error their system charges the higher amount anyway.

I find the latter unlikely. If that were the case, someone needs to talk to the banking regulation authorities to look into the processes and systems. That leaves the former. The customer/consumer and the bank are in a dispute about the terms of their contract.

The details of how to sue depend on the national legal system. Before a lawsuit is filed (possibly a high expense/high risk approach), one might talk to consumer protection advocates to see if the problem is part of a pattern with that bank, if others have protested the charges and won, or lost.